# How to allow Windows Store apps and the Windows Store to pass the Windows Firewall

Tags: windows, windows-8, firewall, windows-store

I use the Windows 8 firewall and I wanted it to be more secure, so I block incoming and outgoing connections. Unfortunately I realized that the Windows Store did not work as well and all applications from the store too. Then I checked the list of applications from where I can add exceptions, and I couldn't find anything that could be linked to the Windows Store (WSService). Could anyone help me create fast and simple exceptions for their proper functioning?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Windows Firewall
2. Click `Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall` from the left-side pane.
3. Click `Change settings` [ Admin rights might be required]
4. Select the check box for the app you want to allow
5. Select `Network type` and click `OK`

For details:

[Here is the link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-firewall-from-start-to-finish) , Microsoft has explained a way around to allow the apps to work fine having Firewall enabled at the back end

check the **Allow an app to receive info through the firewall** heading